# HTML5, Codeigniter and history rewrite / refresh

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter, history

I am using HTML5 boilerplate with a codeigniter backend. I am actually new to codeigniter.
I have created a controller called home.php that defines the html5 view in index and have a couple of other methods/actions called page and catalog.

*EDIT* Updated the question because it was not so clear */EDIT*

I can load my data from the codeigniter. I have a url that calls those data from the controller: /index.php/home/page/xxx (where xxx is the content I have for each page). In my /index.php/home/index controller is the main (and only) template view that I load. When a user clicks on the menu (that is the only static block), I do these things:

1. construct a url from the

   data-action, data-controller, data-pageid variables.

   load the url using div.load() from jquery

   the url is actually the codeigniter controller that serves me the data back

   the "aside" area of the screen is now loaded with the data from the controller and rendered (I do some maths for full screen and width/height checks)

   I create an html5 history entry to "trick" the browser that it has loaded a different page (and use that for google analytics).

Now the thing is that this happens when I do it from /index.php/home/index

If I do it from a page url (for example: /index.php/home/page/100 ), it will **correctly** render only the content (because that is what the controller does). What I would like to do
is that when a user clicks that url (for example he found it from google), the process would be:

1. Render the main template page
2. Fetch the data using the same jquery load process to the aside area of the graphics
3. do the following steps mentioned above.

So my problem is to trigger the rendering and the load fetching from another url that can be used to fetch only data. I am trying to do this because I don't want to do reload on the page, if that was the case, then I would make a static aside view for each page type I am having.

One method mentioned below is to use SESSION to check if the view is loaded, so that I would reload that. Is there a more codeigniter-y way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked [here yet](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)? and possibly [here too](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: This is what I did. Except my actions return JSON/html data that are then used as subviews (ajax) from jquery using $.load(). I am trying to make a non reloadable site. For example I have /index.php/home/page/100 that brings back a json with title/subtitle/content. If I use that in the browser, it returns me the json as supposed. But I want to use an action that: loads the main template view (index), THEN loads the data returned from /home/page/100 like I have triggered the menu item from the home/index action

Comment: I use CI and .load all the time, in your controller simple load a view as normal like `$this->load->view('someView')` or `$this->load->view('someView', $dataArray)` and use the link to that controller as your url on .load in jquery

Comment: it's called "working with view partials"

Comment: Is there a way to detect if the view is loaded or no?

Comment: I don't think so, but you could test for the type of request.  A `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header would indicate an AJAX request, although this is not foolproof or secure.

Comment: Or you could set a session variable, and only send the full HTML when that session variable is not set.

Comment: Hmm interesting about the session, I'll try it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example of loading view partials.

First create your main page and load that, which you seem to have down pat.

In you main view, in jQuery use something like the following:

```
$("#eleID").load(
    '<?= site_url('yourController/yourLoadFunc'); ?>', // url to your load function in controller
    function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpReques) { // function to execute when load is complete
        // responseText is your view, OR json data if not a view recieved
        // however, for loading a view partial, you don't need the json data here
        // as you know, you can insert data in a view via the CI load view call
        // so simply make an html page of what you want your sub-view to be
        // complete with vars for data, and when your controller for this jQuery call
        // returns the view, insert the data as normal makeing
        // $this->load->view('yourSubView', $dataArray);
        // the last line of the function this load call refers too
    }
);
```

if any of that doesn't make sense let me know and i'll try to help correct it till it does

Comment: I am adding some info to my question because I am afraid I was not so clear.

Answer (score 0):

To supply the approach that you are asking for, I would still use the session approach. If your session property is not set load the outer view elements either side of your content block:

```
//main controller index method
public function index($var1)
{
    //do the stuff you need to prepare your page

    //load session library if not autoloaded
    $this->load->library('session');
    //get the current session value
    $isLoaded = $this->session->userdata('is_loaded');
    //set a new session value
    $this->session->userdata('is_loaded','some_value');

    //display header for new users only
    if($isLoaded === false) $this->load->view('above_content_view');
    $this->load->view('requested_content_view');
    //display footer for new users only
    if(isLoaded === false) $this->load->view('below_content_view');

}
```

This will deliver the entire page only if the session variable is `false`, which CI returns if the value is not set. I think that is preferable to only delivering the HTML frame from an SEO point of view.

Comment: What I am trying to do ultimately is this http://www.queness.com/resources/html/ajax/ only operated by codeigniter to bring me the data, and without history.js -- pure html5.

Comment: Absolutely, and this controller snippet should let you do that. If you hit the page without session being set the outer html view (split into 2 parts) is delivered around the content. Otherwise, only the content region is delivered.  This is preferable because robots and users without JavaScript should still be able to see the contents of the page they requested, but users with JavaScript will then enjoy the benefits of no more page loads as they browse your site.  You could even take this further by tracking which outer view is used, so you can deliver new outers for certain pages if required

Comment: I am taking this further on a current project, and having the page render with normal links that will reload the page, but then replacing all the links on the fly with JavaScript for those who support it.  The newly added link actions call via AJAX to a different controller that can more efficiently deliver specific content regions without worrying about the extra page actions in my main controller.

Comment: Is the __construct method useful here? I mean, can we do some checks there? I disabled the history change events for a while, I am having some caching trouble (and I don't know if it's html5 boilerplate, codeigniter or apache)

Comment: yes, you could do your session checks in the constructor to save repeating them in every action method you make.

Comment: Bringing this thread from the dead, after holidays, I did put a "session" check to see if the view is loaded, but now it renders me the whole page (good), but my data are written all over the page, and not in the designated window of load. So the trigger is correct, but now I need to see how the data will be inserted to a specific div.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think to do is to use hashchange event in the browsers.
You will have to craft your URLs to something like

```
/index.php/home/#!page-100
```

The `#!` is for the google ajax crawlers to treat them as different pages.
And you will need to fire a hashchange event when the page loads.

That way when anyone clicks your URL from anywhere the index method from home controller will be executed.
There on page load, you check for any hash changes using JS. and you make an AJAX request to the page method of the home controllers to fetch the content specified the hash.

You can find this plugin here
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

The plugin itself makes the entry to the browser history.

Comment: Broncha, there is the HTML5 history object (that's why I am including HTML5 History on the question title) that does the hashchange things on the fly. Thanks for noting it though, I needed that too for HTML4/XHTML projects :)

Comment: Then aren't you done! any link would land on the home controller. You have the hash change handler. And when the page loads you fire a hash change event.. which will load the respective view using AJAX